# Data Extension field type: Number. What is exactly?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration

What does exactly `Number` mean? Is it integer, long, float or double?

In case of integer/long, how can I store decimal placers?

In case of float/double:

do I need to specify number of decimal placers and precision?

what is decimal separator when we need to import data? `.` or `,`

what is decimal separator when we need to export data? `.` or `,`

Decimal placers has no maximum or data will be truncated?

17.012345678912 stores completely?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number is an integer and cannot store decimal values, you use the Decimal data type for this.

Any other info can be found here: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/data_types/

Comment: The linked page isn't working any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Number is an integer between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,648 and cannot store decimal values. You must use the Decimal data type for this.

When creating a decimal field using Fields.Add in SSJS, you do need to specify the the precision (the number of digits to the left of the decimal) and the scale (the number to the right of the decimal) like this:

```
de.Fields.Add = { Name : "DEC_FLD", FieldType : "DECIMAL", MaxLength : 15, Scale : 2}
```

When using CONVERT in SQL to import a string, it looks like this:

```
CONVERT(decimal(15,2), A_STRING_FIELD) AS A_DECIMAL_FLD
```

Decimal does have a maximum. The sum of precision and scale must not exceed 38.

[Here is the current link to Data Types for Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_extension_data_types.htm&type=5).

Comment: That linked page plus seeing your example where you set the decimal maxlength to 15 and the scale to 2 is exactly what I needed to create data extensions with decimal fields using the soap API.